# Protecting contents against download and against unauthorized users

Tags: iis-8

I have a content delivery server where I keep a variety of file types such as HTML, Video, Audio, Image, etc. I have done this by just creating a website in IIS with no code (No ASP.Net, PHP, etc), and yeah just a blank website in which I have copied my files. Alongside with this server, I have a web server which is fully distinct and it has been written using ASP.Net Core and it is responsible for authenticating users, delivering pages, etc.

The problem is that the content preserved in that CDN is unprotected and now, any user can request those materials. With respect to the fact that I have no code in there, is there any way to define to IIS to only authorize request which have `a valid authorization token in their headers`? (how to validate the header is another problem)

Comment: That's what exactly you should check CDN documentation. CDN service providers such as Azure do support authentication, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-token-auth

Comment: @LexLi: Who's talking or asking about Azure, you ok? **IIS**

Comment: Reformat your question please to eliminate the ambiguity. If you are using raw IIS, not any other CDN service, you can remove all CDN references. In the meantime, raw IIS won't give you any authentication suitable (Windows/basic and so on are not), so your "blank site" approach won't work. Do use ASP.NET or PHP or even C++ to extend IIS and add suitable authentication/authorization.

Comment: @LexLi: `Do use ASP.NET or PHP or even C++ to extend IIS and add suitable authentication/authorization` you are really smart I think :)

Comment: Is it really difficult to use your fingers and search with a few keywords like "extend IIS C++" which can easily lead you to tons of materials like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/develop-a-native-cc-module-for-iis ? You can also use .NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net .